# Is there anything I can do to get my split() function working?

Tags: python, split, pycharm, python-re

I just want to ask if how can I get my split function working properly

```
x_value = "7383 + 4536"
```

i used pytesseract to extract that string

```
if '+' in x_value is not None:
    x_value = re.split('[+`]', x_value)
    try:
        x_value = int(x_value[0]), int(x_value[1])
    except:
        x_value = int(x_value[0]), int(x_value[2])
print(x_value)
```

but my problem is it print outs

```
['7383 + 4536\n\x0c']
```

so...guys i really need your help guys...im just a 14 years old boy who wants to learn programming..its been 3 weeks since i started learning... this is my first project...i hope you can help me improve...

Comment: What do you mean by "working"? what would "working" look like?

Comment: Using `re.split('[+`]', '123 + 456')` I get `['123 ', ' 456']`, so I'm not able to reproduce your result

Comment: Just use `int(x_value[0].strip())`, and so. You want to remove spaces from the input, before to convert to integer. Note: you have also a FF

Answer (score 1):

The `+` in a regular expression means "one or more" of the previous item.

You should escape it with `\` in your pattern to be treated as the `+` character.

(Also, beware the `\` must be escaped, or string prefixed by `r`.)

```
x_value = re.split( r'[\+`]', x_value )
```

Comment: i still get the same results:‹

Comment: thank you for your response:› but it still doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your code line-by-line.

```py
if '+' in x_value is not None:
    x_value = re.split('[+`]', x_value)
    try:
        x_value = int(x_value[0]), int(x_value[1])
    except:
        x_value = int(x_value[0]), int(x_value[2])
print(x_value)
```

#### `if '+' in x_value is not None:`

This line is incorrect. `'+' in x_value` will be evaluated to either `True` or `False`, so therefore the `is not None` is not your intention. Say `+` is inside `x_value`, then the `if` statement evaluates to:

```
if True is not None
```

Which is of course `True`. Say `+` is **not** inside `x_value`, then:

```
if False is not None
```

This also evaluates to `True`. The correct way is simply:

```
if '+' in x_value:
```

#### `x_value = re.split('[+.]', x_value)`

This was covered by @Didier Trosset.

#### `try` block

```
try:
    x_value = int(x_value[0]), int(x_value[1])
except:
    x_value = int(x_value[0]), int(x_value[2])
```

If your input is say `1 + 2`, then the correct regex line should return to you a list with two objects `[1, 2]`. In this case, the `try` statement is catching (if an error is thrown) in the case the regex line *does not return 2 numbers*, but when catching the error, it attempts to *add* a third number `x_value[2]`, which would also throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something more simple, like this:

```py
x_value = "7383 + 4536"

if "+" in x_value:
    values = [int(value.strip()) for value in x_value.split("+")]
    print(values)
```

It prints `[7383, 4536]`.

The nice thing is that you don't need any regexp to make work.